# XmlSerializer to serialize a class, i want child tag names as given in a public property

Tags: .net, xmlserializer

I am using XmlSerializer to serialize a class, which has a list of objects 
as part of it.Now what is happening is, the child tag names are taking the name from the class name but what i want is it'd take the name from a public field inside child class.Please help, which xml attribute should i use to make it work.

I have this code:

```
SessionAnalyser sa = new SessionAnalyser();
Circle c = new Circle();
c.Name = "AP";// I want this property as the TAG Name
```

XML O/P i am getting:

```
<SessionAnalyser>
<Circle>
<Name>AP</Name>
...
</Circle>
</SessionAnalyser>
```

Required XML O/P:

```
<SessionAnalyser>
<AP>
...
</AP>
</SessionAnalyser>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` does not support that, note least because it would have no way of deserializing it since it can't know that `.Name` maps to the AP in `<AP>` in advance.

To do that with `XmlSerializer` you would have to implement `IXmlSerializable`, which is a lot of work; however, I suspect using something like a DOM (`XElement`, for example) would be much easier at that point.

**TL;DR;** version

> don't use `XmlSerializer` for a scenario that `XmlSerializer` doesn't help you with

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can make in on your own by implementing [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)